# Using the Login Button plugin to get fb userid BEFORE user Authenticates

Tags: authentication, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-login

So when you put the login button plugin on an app it seems to display the user's friends that are using said app. It displays this even to users that have NOT allowed the app access yet. For example, if you go to "Henry's Cooking App" but have never Logged into the app thru facebook, it will still show you your friends that are using the app.

What I'm trying to do is use this feature to grab an array of fb-userids from the plugin so I can do a query on my DB to show the POTENTIAL user a little more info. For example let's say you have 2 friends that already use "Henry's Cooking App": Joe and Karen. If I could get their userid I could then show you something like "Joe just cooked Veal Scallopini, and Karen is perfecting her Tonkatsu Curry".

I know you could do this easily IF you had the authentication token, but that is only obtained after the user logs in. I'm trying to leverage the fact that fb seems to think it's OK to show your friends that are using the app BEFORE you sign up for the app.

The only super hacky way I could think of to do it is the fact that I could pull the href attribute of elements matching $(".uiFacePileItem a") which gives a link to the user profile which I could then grab the username or UID from. This seems like it could break easily though, anyone have a better idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The only super hacky way I could think of to do it is the fact that I could pull the href attribute of elements matching $(".uiFacePileItem a") which gives a link to the user profile which I could then grab the username or UID from.

You can’t do that, because the Facebook login dialogs are not running under your domain – so the Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with the DOM of these dialogs.

> I'm trying to leverage the fact that fb seems to think it's OK to show your friends that are using the app BEFORE you sign up for the app.

Well, it’s certainly (more) OK if *Facebook* does that – because that doesn’t give any information away to third parties (meaning you as the app developer/provider) – only the user sees that.

It would **not** be OK if Facebook would let **you** access this info, at a point where I haven’t even decided to use your app yet – totally a case of *„none of your business”*.

After I decide to use your app, you may have access to certain information. Before that – **No Way, José**.

Comment: Exactly, if you figured out how to do this somehow, it'd be a major bug that would be fixed ASAP

Comment: ah yes that does make sense. just to be clear I had no nefarious intentions. I simply wanted to create a bit more of a personalized landing page by using public (in the context of my app) actions but you are right, a person's friendlist should be protected.